# Strange exceptions while using System.Drawing and System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, memory-management, memory-leaks

While working with the software, after a while, randomly software start generating some exceptions which seems unrelated to my codes.

2 cases of stack traces listed below (from the root):

```
    System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.Image.get_Width()
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Image original)
   at Carane.Portal.Infrastructure.Win.EnterpriseExplorer.LoadNode(ExplorerChildItem itemChild, TreeNode parentNode, Object bo)
   at Carane.Portal.Infrastructure.Win.EnterpriseExplorer.LoadChildNodes(ExplorerItem item, TreeNode parentNode)
   at Carane.Portal.Infrastructure.Win.EnterpriseExplorer.OnEnterpriseExplorerLoad(Object sender, EventArgs e)
...
```

which I can't imagine why `System.Drawing.Image.get_Width()` would throw an exception?!

and the other one is:

```
  at System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.SerializationInvoke(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext& context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(ObjectHolder holder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
...
```

which says that `System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreame`'s constructor is throwing exception.

Why these exceptions are being thrown? There's also some clues which I'm not sure if they're related!

Currently we've installed the Service Pack 1 for Windows 7.

Another thing that might help is this screenshot from `Task Manager`
[image]

It says that program is using about 6000 `handles` and 2000 `GDI object` which I don't know if they're normal.

Comment: Could it be the same cause as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949045/net-bitmap-class-constructor-int-int-and-int-int-pixelformat-throws-argu)?

Comment: Your program is a piggy, exceptions you get are ugly.  Focus on getting the USER Objects down first, that's the biggest problem.  You are using calls like Controls.Clear() and/or Controls.Remove/At() without calling the Dispose() method of the controls you removed.  GDI Objects next, calling the Dispose() method on a bitmap is similarly not optional.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the clues. I'll check them out.

Comment: @HansPassant your answer really helps. As a matter of fact there was a bug inside our framework which didn't dispose grid inline comboboxes. Why don't you post the comment as answer!?

Comment: @Dirk that question is about large bitmaps and finding a memory hole suitable for it. But my images are just 32x32 icons.