# Parameter not valid c#

Tags: c#, image, activereports

I am loading image in my Active Report. I went through many issues and at last I found this solution. But when I tried to run the code I am getting "Parameter not valid" exception.

**Code:**

```
  try
     {

 if (File.Exists(this.txtProtoImage.Value.ToString()))
            {
                this.imgProtoImage.Image = CreateIndexedImage(this.txtProtoImage.Value.ToString());
              //  this.imgProtoImage.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(this.txtProtoImage.Value.ToString());
                this.imgProtoImage.SizeMode = GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.SizeModes.Zoom;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ; // Line 119
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CopyMemory")] 
private extern static void CopyMemory(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, uint length); 

public static Image CreateIndexedImage(string path) { 


using (var sourceImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(path)) { 
    var targetImage = new Bitmap(sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height, 
      sourceImage.PixelFormat); 
    var sourceData = sourceImage.LockBits(
      new Rectangle(0, 0, sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height), 
      ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, sourceImage.PixelFormat); 
    var targetData = targetImage.LockBits(
      new Rectangle(0, 0, sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height), 
      ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, targetImage.PixelFormat); 
    CopyMemory(targetData.Scan0, sourceData.Scan0, 
      (uint)sourceData.Stride * (uint)sourceData.Height); 
    sourceImage.UnlockBits(sourceData); 
    targetImage.UnlockBits(targetData); 
    targetImage.Palette = sourceImage.Palette; ///Exception here
    return targetImage; 
  } 
}
```

**Exception:**

```
 System.ArgumentException was unhandled
      HResult=-2147024809
      Message=Parameter is not valid.
      Source=Series.Presentation
      StackTrace:
   at Series.Presentation.Reports.RevReport.Ma_Format(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\UserNew\NewApp\Presentation\Reports\RevReport.cs:line 119
   at GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.Section.#7Ab()
   at GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.Section.#HBb(SectionReport report, PointF location)
   at #sxA.#vqb.#dzb(Section section)
   at #sxA.#vqb.#vEb()
   at #sxA.#vqb.#bZA(Page newPage, Single left, Single top, Single right, Single bottom, UInt32 flags, UInt32& status)
   at GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport.#4yb()
   at GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport.Run(Boolean syncDocument)
   at GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport.Run()
   at Series.Presentation.View.RevReportViewerWindow.OpenRevReport() in e:\UserNew\NewApp\Presentation\View\RevReportViewerWindow.xaml.cs:line 164
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
      InnerException:
```

**RevReportViewerWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
 public void OpenRevReport()
        {
 Reports.RevReport MaReport = null;
            try
            {
                MaReport = new Reports.RevReport(lstUsers, blnFlag);

                MaReport.Run();

                App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    ReportViewer.Document = MaReport.Document;

                    RevHost.Child = ReportViewer;
                    ReportViewer.ViewType = GrapeCity.Viewer.Common.Model.ViewType.Continuous;
                    ReportViewer.Visible = true;

                    IsBusy = false;
                    BusyContent = "Ready.";
                });

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;  //164th line where the exception is thrown.
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
```

The actual image is a smaller one and I need to show in a full size view.

Kindly help.

Comment: We can't run your code. To see what's going wrong can you please share the exception details (message, type, stacktrace).

Comment: @DirkVollmar: added Excption detail

Comment: @DirkVollmar: InnerException is "null".

Comment: @DirkVollmar: Updated the question for exception.

Comment: One should almost never use `throw ex;` - it will remove important information from the exception (the original call stack). Use a plain `throw;` instead and you will be able to see where the original exception occurred. Could you please update your code and then post the exception with the call stack you then receive?

Comment: @DirkVollmar: Getting same exception after removing "ex". Had few things in Stack Trace, added those.

Comment: GrapeCity touts their support, clearly everybody needs it when they obfuscate their assemblies.  Use a telephone to talk to them.

Comment: If you look carefully at the stacktrace you can see that the problem is in this line: `e:\UserNew\NewApp\Presentation\Reports\RevReport.cs:line 119` - can you show it?

Comment: @HansPassant: The exception seems not to come from the third-party lib.

Comment: @DirkVollmar: Added the line 119 exception.

Comment: @Dirk - the #7Ab() method seems to play a key role.  I have to say, incredibly foolish for companies to obfuscate their code like this and give nobody a decent shot at diagnosing the problem.  It is report generator, not a jet pack.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: Step through your code and see where the exception exactly occurs. I assume it is a GDI+ error from the Bitmap class (GDI+ does not report very good error messages, e.g. it could simply be that the there is not enough contiguous memory available to create the bitmap). The exception line seems a bit strange to me, did you produce the stacktrace with `throw ex;` and not `throw;`?

Comment: @HansPassant: Totally agree on the obfuscation part, but I'd rather suspect a GDI+ problem here like this one you described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1949240/40347

Comment: @DirkVollmar: when debugging i'm getting the error in 164th line where the `sourceImage.Palette` is been set. I tried using `throw`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simplify your `CreateIndexedImage` method:

```
public static Image CreateIndexedImage(string path) 
{ 
    return Image.FromFile(path);
}
```

If you need to create a copy of your image object, you might want to use [`Image.Clone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.image.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public static Image CreateIndexedImage(string path) 
{ 
    using (var sourceImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(path)) 
    { 
        var targetImage = sourceImage.Clone; 

        // manipulate image 
        ...

        return targetImage;
    } 
}
```

Comment: When trying the first method, the reports are generated good for the first time. When i try to run the reports for the second time it throws me `Out of memory exception`. The second method didn't build well. Is it possible to overcome the `Out of memory exception`?

Comment: You need to make sure to properly dispose the image objects returned by `CreateIndexedImage` at some point in time (e.g. when your report is generated).

Comment: Is there anyway that i can dispose once the image is assigned, may be a finally block?