# Why am I getting a 'parameter not valid' exception?

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, dimensions, onpaint

Basically I have no idea why im getting a Parameter not Valid exception because from what I have learned through google, it is a common exception that gives you no insight on whats actually going on behind the scenes, or whats essentially causing the error.

```
public void DecompileMap() {
        tileArray = new Image[rawImageData.Width / 64, rawImageData.Height / 64];
        Bitmap copiedImage = rawImageData.Clone() as Bitmap;
        Bitmap buffer = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(Form1.AssemblyDirectory + @"\Content\Images\blank.png");
        Graphics tempG = Graphics.FromImage(buffer);
        GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
        tempG.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < copiedImage.Height; j+=64) {
            col = 0;
            for (int  i = 0; i < copiedImage.Width; i+=64) {
                tempG.DrawImage(copiedImage, 0, 0, new Rectangle(new Point(j, i), new Size(IMAGE_DIMENSIONS, IMAGE_DIMENSIONS)), units);
                tileArray[row, col] = buffer;
                if (GetMostUsedColor((Bitmap)tileArray[row, col]).R == 255 && GetMostUsedColor((Bitmap)tileArray[row, col]).G == 255 && GetMostUsedColor((Bitmap)tileArray[row, col]).B == 255) {
                    hitboxes.Add(new Rectangle(new Point(j, i), new Size(buffer.Width, buffer.Height)));
                }
                col++;
            }
            row++;
        }
    }

public static IEnumerable<Color> GetPixels(Bitmap bitmap) {
        for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++) {// I am getting my error here at bitmap.width.
            for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++) {
                Color pixel = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
                yield return pixel;
            }
        }
    }

public static Color GetMostUsedColor(Bitmap bmp) {
        using (var bitmap = bmp) {
            var colorsWithCount =
                GetPixels(bitmap)
                    .GroupBy(color => color)
                    .Select(grp =>
                        new {
                            Color = grp.Key,
                            Count = grp.Count()
                        })
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
                    .Take(1);
            foreach (var colorWithCount in colorsWithCount) {
                return colorWithCount.Color;
            }
        }
        return Color.Black;
    }
```

Any help on this issue would be great thank you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.Net Bitmap class constructor (int, int) and (int, int, PixelFormat) throws ArgumentException on perfectly good arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949045/net-bitmap-class-constructor-int-int-and-int-int-pixelformat-throws-argu)

Comment: So find the duplicate, assuming it exists, and then make it that same format as the others?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this what I did was took this:

```
public static Color GetMostUsedColor(Bitmap bmp) {
    using (var bitmap = bmp) {
        var colorsWithCount =
            GetPixels(bitmap)
                .GroupBy(color => color)
                .Select(grp =>
                    new {
                        Color = grp.Key,
                        Count = grp.Count()
                    })
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
                .Take(1);
        foreach (var colorWithCount in colorsWithCount) {
            return colorWithCount.Color;
        }
    }
    return Color.Black;
}
```

And the added the first line to this;

```
public static Color GetMostUsedColor(Bitmap bmp) {
        Bitmap b = bmp.Clone() as Bitmap; //This line fixes it
        using (var bitmap = b) {// Then edit the previous var named: bmp to b.
            var colorsWithCount =
                GetPixels(bitmap)
                    .GroupBy(color => color)
                    .Select(grp =>
                        new {
                            Color = grp.Key,
                            Count = grp.Count()
                        })
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
                    .Take(1);
            foreach (var colorWithCount in colorsWithCount) {
                return colorWithCount.Color;
            }
        }
        return Color.Black;
    }
```